# Prove device enrollment with MDM from an iOS App

Tags: ios, mdm

We want to make an iOS enterprise app that communicates with a server A - we also have our own MDM server as a separate solution which could communicate with the A server if needed. Q: How can the app securely prove to its server, with every request, that it is coming from a device that is enrolled with the MDM?
I thought there would be some UUID that the app could send together with a signed challenge to A. A would then comunicate with MDM server to validate. But seems impossible.

Comment: The best thing is for your app to only be installed as a managed app by your MDM. Then you know that any device that has the app is managed by your MDM.

Comment: Defeinitely agree with @Paulw11 although there are some hacky ways around it without doing this but even then they're not 100% reliable

Answer (score 0):

The MDM is supposed to handle this. You should not be required to check every request in the API to make sure it is secure. Airwatch, for instance, makes all of your applications downloadable only through their catalog and the agent or vpn system connects when the application is opened. If the user were to attempt to circumvent these limits it unenrolls their device and disallows access until a new enrollment code is issued by your tech department.

Comment: how exactly does an mdm limit the app to work only on an enrolled device? apps can be extracted from devices and installed elsewhere. even enterprise apps

Comment: When an application is placed in a catalog, a profile is built for that application, it downloads the profile with the application and uses that to link the application to the allowed release. This says "Yes. this application is from our network" and then it sends your user data from your device mdm enrollment to the mdm server for authentication checks. If a secure connection is made, it acts as a vpn. If either of these fail, the connection is cut and an error is displayed. For instance if I build an app with the sdk and don't upload the profile, it will fail even though I'm authorized.

Comment: It should also be noted that your network should block request from out of network. For instance, the api for one of my apps can't be contacted from my home network, but if I vpn through using airwatch, I can contact it just fine on any network.

Comment: so you are saying that the app provisioning profile, which is a an enterprise provisioning profile, is somehow tied with the MDM profile? so if someone grabs the app and the provisioning profile they can't just install both in an unenrolled device? If so, that would be awesome and I would be interested to understand how exactly is the provisioning profile of the enterprise app tied with the MDM. Let's not involve VPN into this conversation if possible, nor Airwatch. We don't want to grant VPN access throguh MDM and we cannot block external requests

Comment: There is also an SDK built into the application that handles the connection calls and device validation. I don't know the exact specifics of everything so you can choose one and contact them, they usually provide an architecture map. Simply put, you could release this application on the play store and they won't be able to contact your network. It's not 100%, as nothing is, but it does a good job. You need four components, the app, the mdm installed on device, the app config profile, account associated to the server. You should also know the MDM connection is technically a VPN inside the app.

Comment: let's say that an ill-intended legitimate user (internal attacker in a way) extracts the app from an MDM enrolled device and alters it and installs it on a jailbroken device that is not MDM enrolled. What is stopping the altered app from communicating with the server? The server cannot trust the integrity of the app, unless it queries the MDM server about the integrity of the device. To identify the device, the app would need to provide a form of unique device/app instance identification that cannot be forged - HOW?